# python script stop running but no error showed

Tags: python, error-handling

Working on the following python script but I find difficult to check if it runs fine because I noticed that for some errors the console doesn't show any error.

For example, if I try to print a not defined object like `threadObj` (see line 27) the script doesn't go further and don't even print the string on the same line

Is that the expected behavior?
The issue happen both on windows 10 and linux (raspbian)

```
import json
from math import ceil
import os
import queue
import sys
import subprocess
import time

import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt


def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected to {0} with result code {1}".format(HOST, rc))
    # Subscribe to any hotword topic --- old code:   # client.subscribe("hermes/hotword/default/detected")
    client.subscribe("hermes/hotword/#")

    # Subscribe to any topic starting with 'hermes/intent/'
    client.subscribe('hermes/intent/#')



def on_message(client, userdata, msg):

    print("- Message received on topic {0}: {1}".format(msg.topic, msg.payload))
    print('* ledPulse instance count {0}'.format(threadObj))

    if msg.topic == 'hermes/hotword/default/detected':
        print("Wakeword detected! Wakeword light!")

    if msg.topic == 'hermes/intent/mywai:ShowMarketplace':
        # intent ShowMarketplace light
        print("Intent detected! ShowMarketplace light!")

    if msg.topic == 'hermes/intent/mywai:Shutdown':
        print("Intent detected! Shutdowndevice")
        os.system('shutdown -s')   #windows
        os.system('sudo shutdown now')  #linux



#########################################################################
# MAIN
#########################################################################

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #main()

    HOST = '192.168.1.6'
    PORT = 1883


    client = mqtt.Client()
    client.on_connect = on_connect
    client.on_message = on_message

    client.connect(HOST, PORT, 60)
    client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: My hunch is that `client.loop_forever()` is catching any exceptions raised and doing something else with them other than printing them to the console. You might try using a debugger, like the one in PyCharm, to set a breakpoint where you no exceptions aren't visible from and stepping through to see what's happening.

Comment: Thanks for the hint Ken, it's probably like you said.... I've tried to set breakpoint on the PyCharm debugger but it doesn't show any relevant info (first time I use the debugger, It could be a fault on my side)
I've ended using a try catch to handling the errors, is still a pain because I don't know exactly where the issue is